# PostgreSQL get relative average with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table as follows. The rows are in a specific order.

```
id    |      value
------+---------------------
 1    |        2
 1    |        4     
 1    |        3
 2    |        2
 2    |        2
 2    |        5
```

I would want to group the rows by the column 'id' and get the average of value displayed in each column in terms of the previous values of the column (As explained in the following example within brackets)

```
id    |      value  |    RelativeAverage    
------+-------------+--------------------
 1    |        2    |        (2/1) = 2
 1    |        4    |        (2+4 /2) = 3
 1    |        3    |        (2+4+3 / 3) = 3
 2    |        2    |        (2/1) = 2
 2    |        2    |        (2+2 / 2) = 2
 2    |        5    |        (2+2+5 / 3) = 9
```

Is there an approach with which I can achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Window functions are your friends

Comment: your math is off. 2 + 4 / 2 is 3, yours is 6

Comment: `1+2+5 / 2` should be `1+2+5 / 3`?

Comment: My bad, corrected it

Comment: @Visahan . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless you have a column specifying the ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong query:

```sql
select 
  id, value, 

  sum(value) over(arrangement), rank() over(arrangement),

  sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric / rank() over(arrangement) 
  as relative_average
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by id);
```

Output (wrong):

```
| id | value | sum | rank | relative_average |
|----|-------|-----|------|------------------|
|  1 |     2 |   9 |    1 |                9 |
|  1 |     4 |   9 |    1 |                9 |
|  1 |     3 |   9 |    1 |                9 |
|  2 |     1 |   8 |    1 |                8 |
|  2 |     2 |   8 |    1 |                8 |
|  2 |     5 |   8 |    1 |                8 |
```

You need something that sorts correctly in order for sum and rank to work properly on your actual arrangement of your data. You can use table row's hidden `ctid` field, but that is Postgres-specific

Correct query:

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    sum(value) over(arrangement), rank() over(arrangement),

    sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric / rank() over(arrangement) 
    as relative_average
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by tbl.ctid);
```

Output (correct):

```
| id | value | sum | rank |   relative_average |
|----|-------|-----|------|--------------------|
|  1 |     2 |   2 |    1 |                  2 |
|  1 |     4 |   6 |    2 |                  3 |
|  1 |     3 |   9 |    3 |                  3 |
|  2 |     1 |   1 |    1 |                  1 |
|  2 |     2 |   3 |    2 |                1.5 |
|  2 |     5 |   8 |    3 | 2.6666666666666665 |
```

Best way is to introduce a serial primary key, so doing a running-total(`sum over()`) based on actual arrangement of your data could be achieved.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (ordered_pk serial primary key, "id" int, "value" int)
;

INSERT INTO tbl
    ("id", "value")
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (1, 4),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 5)
;
```

Correct query:

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    sum(value) over(arrangement), rank() over(arrangement),

    sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric / rank() over(arrangement) 
    as relative_average
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by ordered_pk);
```

Output (correct):

```
| id | value | sum | rank |   relative_average |
|----|-------|-----|------|--------------------|
|  1 |     2 |   2 |    1 |                  2 |
|  1 |     4 |   6 |    2 |                  3 |
|  1 |     3 |   9 |    3 |                  3 |
|  2 |     1 |   1 |    1 |                  1 |
|  2 |     2 |   3 |    2 |                1.5 |
|  2 |     5 |   8 |    3 | 2.6666666666666665 |
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f18276/1

You can `order by value`, but it will yield different result, not necessarily wrong output, but different because of different arrangement of values. And then you also need to use `row_number` instead of `rank`/`dense_rank` due to possible duplication of values. Here I made an example of duplicate values.

Correct query:

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    sum(value) over(arrangement),

    row_number() over(arrangement),
    rank() over(arrangement),  
    dense_rank() over(arrangement),    

    sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric / row_number() over(arrangement) 
    as relative_average
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by value)
```

Output:

```
| id | value | sum | row_number | rank | dense_rank |   relative_average |
|----|-------|-----|------------|------|------------|--------------------|
|  1 |     2 |   2 |          1 |    1 |          1 |                  2 |
|  1 |     3 |   5 |          2 |    2 |          2 |                2.5 |
|  1 |     4 |   9 |          3 |    3 |          3 |                  3 |
|  2 |     1 |   1 |          1 |    1 |          1 |                  1 |
|  2 |     2 |   5 |          2 |    2 |          2 |                2.5 |
|  2 |     2 |   5 |          3 |    2 |          2 | 1.6666666666666667 |
|  2 |     5 |  10 |          4 |    4 |          3 |                2.5 |
```

Live test:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2b5aac/1

Answer (score 1):

Not so proud of my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877663/postgresql-get-relative-average-with-group-by/55878800#55878800)

Just use `avg`.

Today I Learned `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`. And it works with the actual arrangement of data even in the absence of a good candidate field for `order by`. It looks like that at least you can get away with using Postgres' hidden `ctid` field, or you can even avoid using serial primary. Recommending though to use serial primary key or date created field to `order by` upon.

Here's a better query. No need to divide, just use `avg`

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    avg(value) over(arrangement rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id);
```

Output

```
| id | value |                avg |
|----|-------|--------------------|
|  1 |     2 |                  2 |
|  1 |     4 |                  3 |
|  1 |     3 |                  3 |
|  2 |     1 |                  1 |
|  2 |     2 |                1.5 |
|  2 |     5 | 2.6666666666666665 |
```

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    sum(value) over(arrangement), rank() over(arrangement),

    sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric / rank() over(arrangement) 
    as relative_average,    

    avg(value) over(arrangement rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by id);
```

Output:

```
| id | value | sum | rank | relative_average |                avg |
|----|-------|-----|------|------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |     2 |   9 |    1 |                9 |                  2 |
|  1 |     4 |   9 |    1 |                9 |                  3 |
|  1 |     3 |   9 |    1 |                9 |                  3 |
|  2 |     1 |   8 |    1 |                8 |                  1 |
|  2 |     2 |   8 |    1 |                8 |                1.5 |
|  2 |     5 |   8 |    1 |                8 | 2.6666666666666665 |
```

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    sum(value) over(arrangement), rank() over(arrangement),

    sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric / rank() over(arrangement) 
    as relative_average,

    avg(value) over(arrangement rows between unbounded preceding and current row)    
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by tbl.ctid);
```

Output:

```
| id | value | sum | rank |   relative_average |                avg |
|----|-------|-----|------|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |     2 |   2 |    1 |                  2 |                  2 |
|  1 |     4 |   6 |    2 |                  3 |                  3 |
|  1 |     3 |   9 |    3 |                  3 |                  3 |
|  2 |     1 |   1 |    1 |                  1 |                  1 |
|  2 |     2 |   3 |    2 |                1.5 |                1.5 |
|  2 |     5 |   8 |    3 | 2.6666666666666665 | 2.6666666666666665 |
```

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    sum(value) over(arrangement), rank() over(arrangement),

    sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric / rank() over(arrangement) 
    as relative_average,

    avg(value) over(arrangement rows between unbounded preceding and current row)    
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by ordered_pk);
```

Output:

```
| id | value | sum | rank |   relative_average |                avg |
|----|-------|-----|------|--------------------|--------------------|
|  1 |     2 |   2 |    1 |                  2 |                  2 |
|  1 |     4 |   6 |    2 |                  3 |                  3 |
|  1 |     3 |   9 |    3 |                  3 |                  3 |
|  2 |     1 |   1 |    1 |                  1 |                  1 |
|  2 |     2 |   3 |    2 |                1.5 |                1.5 |
|  2 |     5 |   8 |    3 | 2.6666666666666665 | 2.6666666666666665 |
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f18276/9

`rows between unbounded preceding and current row` can be also written as `rows unbounded preceding` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f18276/11

---

And here's the result with `order by value` when value have duplicates.

```sql
select 
    id, value, 

    sum(value) over(arrangement),

    row_number() over(arrangement) as rn,
    rank() over(arrangement) as rank,  
    dense_rank() over(arrangement) drank,    

    trunc( sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric 
        / row_number() over(arrangement), 2) as ra__rn,
    trunc( sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric 
        / row_number() over(arrangement), 2) as ra__rank,    
    trunc( sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric 
        / row_number() over(arrangement), 2) as ra__drank,        

    trunc( avg(value) over(arrangement 
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 2) as ra
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by value)
```

Output:

```
| id | value | sum | rn | rank | drank | ra__rn | ra__rank | ra__drank |   ra |
|----|-------|-----|----|------|-------|--------|----------|-----------|------|
|  1 |     2 |   2 |  1 |    1 |     1 |      2 |        2 |         2 |    2 |
|  1 |     3 |   5 |  2 |    2 |     2 |    2.5 |      2.5 |       2.5 |  2.5 |
|  1 |     4 |   9 |  3 |    3 |     3 |      3 |        3 |         3 |    3 |
|  2 |     1 |   1 |  1 |    1 |     1 |      1 |        1 |         1 |    1 |
|  2 |     2 |   5 |  2 |    2 |     2 |    2.5 |      2.5 |       2.5 |  1.5 |
|  2 |     2 |   5 |  3 |    2 |     2 |   1.66 |     1.66 |      1.66 | 1.66 |
|  2 |     5 |  10 |  4 |    4 |     3 |    2.5 |      2.5 |       2.5 |  2.5 |
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2b5aac/16

And here's the result with `order by ordered_pk` when value have duplicates.

```sql
select 
    id, value,

    sum(value) over(arrangement),

    row_number() over(arrangement) as rn,
    rank() over(arrangement) as rank,  
    dense_rank() over(arrangement) drank,    

    trunc( sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric 
        / row_number() over(arrangement), 2) as ra__rn,
    trunc( sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric 
        / row_number() over(arrangement), 2) as ra__rank,    
    trunc( sum(value) over(arrangement)::numeric 
        / row_number() over(arrangement), 2) as ra__drank,        

    trunc( avg(value) over(arrangement 
    rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 2) as ra
from tbl
window arrangement as (partition by id order by ordered_pk)
```

```
| id | value | sum | rn | rank | drank | ra__rn | ra__rank | ra__drank |   ra |
|----|-------|-----|----|------|-------|--------|----------|-----------|------|
|  1 |     2 |   2 |  1 |    1 |     1 |      2 |        2 |         2 |    2 |
|  1 |     4 |   6 |  2 |    2 |     2 |      3 |        3 |         3 |    3 |
|  1 |     3 |   9 |  3 |    3 |     3 |      3 |        3 |         3 |    3 |
|  2 |     1 |   1 |  1 |    1 |     1 |      1 |        1 |         1 |    1 |
|  2 |     2 |   3 |  2 |    2 |     2 |    1.5 |      1.5 |       1.5 |  1.5 |
|  2 |     2 |   5 |  3 |    3 |     3 |   1.66 |     1.66 |      1.66 | 1.66 |
|  2 |     5 |  10 |  4 |    4 |     4 |    2.5 |      2.5 |       2.5 |  2.5 |
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/baaf9/2

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that you have an ordering column in the table, then what you want is:

```
select t.*,
       avg(value) over (partition by id
                        order by ?
                        rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                       ) as running_avg
from t;
```

The `?` is the ordering column.

In other words, Postgres has a single built-in function that does exactly what you want -- and the function happens to be standard SQL.

The window frame using `rows` is required, because the default is `range`.

If you do not have an ordering column, then you should add one.  I strongly advise you to *NOT* use `ctid` for this purpose.  It might seem like it works on small sets of data, but it is not stable over time and it might not work on larger sets of data.

If you expect your data to be ordered by inserts, then use a `serial` column to capture the insert order.